# How can I access the n-th item of a Firebase query object?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to sort my data with the following command:

```
Query queryref = mDBRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(100);
```

Now, I want access to the elements of `queryref`, but in a way that they are ordered from 1 to 100, the best would be some timestamp sort.

How can I do this in an efficient way (not too many databaserequests, good data structure, scalable)?